# Error: Could not find or load main class Planet

Tags: java, netbeans, enums, cygwin

I am working on the Java tutorials on the Oracle web site on windows 7 using Netbeans 8.0 and 8.1  on Windows 7 Enterprise.

I have thus far worked through the Java Language examples, and have no problems in 
compiling and running the examples. However I ran into an issue trying to work on the Enum Type example Planet.java here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

I had no problems with the EnumTest example, but attempting to run the Planet.java example in the Netbeans 8.0 terminal $java Planet 175 i got the error: Could not find or load main class Planet.  I know that this is not a classpath issue because I checked classpath issues very early on when running all the examples in the oracle tutorial up to this point.

I am thinking it might be weirdness running the terminal in Netbeans on windows which required downloading cygwin. Perhaps the integration between the cygwin path and the Netbeans path in windows?

As always thanks.

Comment: Weird question but are you sure you compiled your code?

Answer (score 1):

I checked command `java Planet.java 175` it somehow worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] attempting to run the `Planet.java` example in the Netbeans 8.0 terminal `java Planet 175` i got the error: `Could not find or load main class Planet`. I know that this is not a classpath issue because I checked classpath issues very early on when running all the examples in the oracle tutorial up to this point.

For the `java Planet 175` command to work, it is expected that there is a `Planet.class` in the same directory. Run `ls` to confirm that. If there is no such file, but you have `Planet.java`, then compile it with `javac Planet.java`. That should create `Planet.class`, and then `java Planet 175` should work.

... but as you say it doesn't... This can happen if you have `CLASSPATH` set, and it doesn't contain `.` (current directory). Check the value of your `CLASSPATH`. You can also force the classpath using the `-cp` flag. So this should *really* work:

```
java -cp . Planet 175
```

Comment: Yup, compiled Planet.java, have Planet.class in the same directory but still getting the error. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Thanks janos. I have done everything as specified in your update, but i am still getting the error message. Thanks for your help. i will try and figure it out. Regards, anonymous